# Do 'Salt water toilets' belong here or on Sustainability.SE?

Tags: discussion, support

I think the question [Why don't toilets use saltwater?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/8209/why-dont-toilets-use-saltwater) should be on [Sustainability.SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/)

Shall we recommend moving it?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure sustainability is the right place. I do agree that it is off topic here though.

Comment: It depends on the Focus of the question. It could be Physics or Chemistry - e.g. if the question was about corrosion.

Comment: Not physics, not chemistry. I'd go for sustainability because the implications of salt water use are municipal and infrastructure, not (earth) science.

Comment: I suggest a migration to there, instead of simply closing the question.

Comment: I agree it is more appropriate for sustainability

Answer (score 6):

I agree, the question fits much better on Sustainability SE than here.

The OP already [cross-posted the same question on Sustainability SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/5354/99) (where it got a few upvotes), so the question here can be closed.